# Getting syntax erorr 1064 when creating a temporary table using mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, temp-tables

i keep getting syntax error near create table in line 2. Please what can i do about it. I have tried and search everywhere to my knowledge.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE #percentpopulationvaccinated
(
continent VARCHAR(200),
location VARCHAR(200),
date DATE,
population INT,
new_vaccinations NUMERIC,
currentPeopleVaccinated NUMERIC
)
INSERT INTO #percentpopulationvaccinated
SELECT dea.continent, dea.location, dea.date, dea.population, vac.new_vaccinations, SUM(CAST(vac.new_vaccinations as unsigned)) OVER (Partition By dea.location ORDER BY dea.location, dea.date) AS currentPeopleVaccinated
FROM portfolioproject.coviddeaths dea
INNER JOIN portfolioproject.covidvaccinations vac
    ON dea.location = vac.location
    AND dea.date = vac.date
WHERE dea.continent is not null
SELECT*, (currentPeopleVaccinated/population)*100
FROM #percentpopulationvaccinated
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't use `#` as the prefix of temporary tables. That's SQL-Server syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL client treats `#` and the text that follows it on the same line as a comment. This means as far as MySQL knows, you have written this query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE 
(
...
```

There is no name for the temporary table. No wonder you got a syntax error!

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comments.html for information on MySQL's comment syntax.

Comment: Hi, i tried what you said, removed the hashtag but keep getting error. this time its was the INSERT into

Comment: It looks like you don't have semicolons to terminate each statement. Each statement needs a semicolon. You should read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/entering-queries.html

Answer (score -1):

Try this command for temporary tables:

```
SELECT dea.continent, dea."location", dea."date", dea.population, 
vac.new_vaccinations, SUM(vac.new_vaccinations) OVER (PARTITION BY 
dea."location" ORDER BY dea."location",dea."date") as 
RollingPeopleVaccinated
INTO TEMPORARY TABLE percentpopulationvaccinated
FROM "CovidDeaths" as dea
JOIN "CovidVaccinations" as vac
ON dea."date" = vac."date" AND dea."location" = vac."location"
WHERE dea.continent IS NOT NULL AND dea.continent !=''

SELECT *,(RollingPeopleVaccinated/population)*100 as rol_per_pop FROM 
percentpopulationvaccinated
```

Comment: The OP has tagged MySQL. Why are you offering an answer for PostGreSQL?

Comment: Because i had the same error on Postgres doing the same Project that he is doing. Since there's no much difference between Mysql et Postgres it can work in his case